# Emacs 23 - How to prevent from backtrace buffer to pop-up

Tags: emacs, backtrace

Each time I scroll top down / top up a buffer the *Backtrace* buffer pops-up and takes half the size of my window, this is quit annoying.
Especially as I don't use at all this buffer, so does anyone know how to prevent Bracktrace to pop-up?

I would be grateful. :)

Comment: I don't believe that I've ever used Emacs 23, but perhaps you have something similar to a debug setting like this:  `(setq debug-on-error t)`  If you comment out that setting, then detailed backtracing might be eliminated.  However, the beginning or ending of buffer messages that I see in the latest version of Emacs Trunk do not generate a detailed backtrace message.

Comment: Normal editing should not bring up such a backtrace, even if you have set `debug-on-error`, so please show us the backtrace you get.

Answer (score 2):

lawlist is correct; this is certainly a consequence of the `debug-on-error` variable being set.

If you're not setting it yourself, then it must be a third-party library. You could use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `rgrep` <kbd>RET</kbd> `debug-on-error` <kbd>RET</kbd> (or maybe `debug-on-error t`) on your site-lisp and custom lisp directories, to help track down which library is responsible.

If you happen to use `nxhtml`, then it's likely to be that at fault (I'm don't think it's been updated anytime recently, and the last version I saw still had this issue in the code). Look in `nxhtml-base.el` and comment out the offending line (or look in `autostart.el` if you don't have the nxhtml-base.el file).

Answer (score 0):

I used emacs23 this past few years, but ​​multiples updates packages (especially Python-for-Emacs) have bound me this morning to upgrade to 24.
I have no problems now.

Thanks you for your time and your answers.